# keep data in controller while routing in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-ng-route

I have following problem:

In AngularJS app I use `$routeProvider` to load different parts into application

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
  $routeProvider.when('/users', {templateUrl: 'partials/users.html', controller: 'UserCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

In my UserCtrl I display list of users, which I can manipulate. I read the list of users from json, which looks like this:

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"name":"test user 2","mail":"test@gmail.com","ringer":true,"active":true},{"id":2,"name":"test user 1","mail":"test@page.com","ringer":false,"active":true},{"id":3,"name":"admin","mail":"admin@example.com","ringer":false,"active":true}]}
```

In `users.html` I have controller, which calls service to load the data

```
    'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', [function() {

  }])
  .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

  }])
  .controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'UsersService', function($scope, UsersService) {
    //alert(UsersService.fetchData().length);
    UsersService.fetchData().then( function( data ){
      // Do whatever you want with data, like:
      $scope.users = data.users;
    });

    this.users = $scope.users;
    this.selected = [];
    this.searchTerm = '';

    $scope.selected = this.selected;    
  }])
;
```

And finally the service:

```
    'use strict';

/* Services */


// Demonstrate how to register services
// In this case it is a simple value service.
angular.module('myApp.services', []).
  value('version', '0.1')
  .factory('UsersService', function($http, $q) {

  var data = [];

  function fetchData() {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    if ( _isDataPresent() ) {
      deffered.resolve( _returnData() );
    } else {
      //var deffered = $q.defer();
      $http.get('php/users.php')
      .success(function (d) {
        deffered.resolve(d);
        data = d.users;
      });
      return deffered.promise;
    }
  }

  function _isDataPresent() {
    return data.length;
  }

  function _returnData() {
    return data;
  }

  return { fetchData : fetchData };

});
```

The problem which I have is following: Every time I load `users.html`, the data are reloaded from json file. I want to load data only once and keep them in my controller. Now, when I make some changes to the data, switch to different view and come back, all changes are lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Zbynek

Comment: Create a service that stores your data the first time is requested, it save the value. Then, for all the next request, you can return it "cached" value. Since controllers are changing all the time, you cant "store" the data there.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any example?

Comment: I think you need to store the JSON data in localstorage/cookie, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple example of what I meant:

```
.factory( 'UsersService', function( $http, $q ) {

  var users = [];

  function fetchUsers() {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    if ( _areUsersPresent() ) {
      deffered.resolve( _getUsers() );
    } else {
      $http.get('php/users.php')
      .success(function (response) {
        deffered.resolve(response.users);
        data = d.users;
      });
      return deffered.promise;
    }
  }

  function _areUsersPresent() {
    return ( users.length() ) ? true : false;
  }

  function _getUsers() {
    return users;
  }

  function setUsers( newUsers ) {
    users = newUsers;
  }

  return { fetchUsers : fetchUsers, setUsers : setUsers };

});
```

You can use this on your controllers as

```
UsersService.fetchUsers().then( function( users ){
  // Do whatever you want with data, like:
  $scope.users = users;
});
```

And, whenever you update the users on your controllers, you have to update the content of the service:

```
// Doing operations with $scope.service, when finish with them:
UsersService.setUsers( $scope.users );
```

Comment: This returns object, with function then, catch and finally and objects $$scope and __proto__. How do I get data from this object?

Comment: Thanks - just one comment - it seems to me, that FetchData returns promise in case when the data are loaded from json, and data (array), if _returnData() is called

Comment: It returns promises in both cases. The difference is that the first time, it must actually fetch the data from your endpoint. On the second and next ones, it will resolve the promise right away, without doing http request, since its present on that service. But in both cases, it returns a promise (this way, you got a consistence api).

Comment: Ok, I see what you meant. Sorry, I answer too fast maybe. Now its fixed, both are arrays :)

Comment: Strangely, the second time I route to this partial, I get Error: UsersService.fetchData(...) is undefined. The object UsersService exists, but for some reason it is missing the function

Comment: Thats... very strange... can you create a jsfiddle or give me more details ? If your service is injected on the right controller, it should work properly.

Comment: I have added contents of files services.js and controllers.js and I will try to prepare jsfiddle. Thanks for the effort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80863/discussion-between-avcajaraville-and-zbynek).